# The use of the definite article with the word "answer" in context

Tags: articles, definite-article

Let's say I am teaching math and I tell my students that if they don't know answers to my questions, they can ask me. I am not talking about specific questions and answers about math, but rather questions and answers in general. Do I have to use the before *answers*? For example:

> If you dont know (**the**) answers to questions, feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and example are slightly different.

If you use “MY questions” you are specifying which questions and need to use ”the”. If you use “questions” alone, you do not need to use the.

“If you don’t know answers to questions, feel free to ask me.”

(This is correct, but a very broad category, as it implies any question conceivable, and any number.)

“If you don’t know THE answers to MY questions, feel free to ask me.”

“If you don’t know THE answers to A FEW questions, feel free to ask me.”

(These ways indicates which questions you are referring to)